# LabView communication with WM_Copydata

Tags: c, labview

I am attempting to use LabView in order to perform data acquisition for my system while still keeping the existing C program functioning as usual. I hope to achieve this by using the wm_copdata command and communicating over dll.

Unfortunately, most of the examples I have found for doing this are from a much earlier version of LabView or only support Windows 32-bit. The C portion of the system is completely implemented and I think I understand what is going on fairly well. Any assistance with the LabView portion would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no hiring site.

Comment: I don't see anything off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you seek is here: 
http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/WM-copydata/td-p/2416948

The user EWiebe posted the code for a small utility DLL that is then invoked from LabVIEW.